# A series that is algebraic?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, power-series

This question is a follow-up of question [A series that is rational?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365328/a-series-that-is-rational) . Let $k=\mathbb F_q(T)$. Can one prove (or disprove) that the series $\sum_{n\ge0}(1-TX^{q^n})Y^{q^n}\in k[[X,Y]]$ is algebraic over $k(X,Y)$? In the mentioned link it is proved that the series does not belong to $k(X,Y)$.

If the series would be $\sum_{n\ge0}(1-X^{q^n})Y^{q^n}$, it is  easy to prove...

Comment: The series is $f-Tg$ where $f=\sum_{n\geq0}Y^{q^n}$ and  $g=\sum_{n\geq0}(XY)^{q^n}$. Both $f$ and $g$ are algebraic since $f^q-f=-Y$ and $g^q-g=-XY$.